# Why do we need the limiting function to be finite almost everywhere for Egorov's theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Why is Egorov's theorem false if our limiting function f is not finite ae? Intuitively, I think it makes a lot of sense because once we shrink epsilon to be significantly smaller than the measure of the points of X where f is infinite, we can not get any uniform convergence in these points. From introductory analysis, uniform convergence graphically means there is an epsilon band around our function where for $n>N$, all $f_n$ is within this band. But for infinity, there is no such thing as an epsilon band around infinity we can speak of, so that is the reason why convergence cannot be uniform. Is this roughly correct?

Comment: Where does the proof use the finiteness of $f$?

Comment: Just take $f_n=n$ for all $n$ to find a counter-example when finiteness of the limit is violated.

Comment: @Michael $f_n = n$ does not converge pointwise anywhere since for each $x$, $f_n(x)$ is not Cauchy. Unless you mean convergence in an extended sense.

Comment: The question asks why do we require the limiting function $f$ to be finite almost everywhere.  My example shows what happens if the limiting function is infinite.  If you require $f(x)$ to be finite whenever $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ then that removes the asker's question completely, as it was already assumed $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for almost all $x$.